# Use google.auth from container running on COS in compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

I am trying to create credentials using `google.auth.default()` from inside a container that is running on COS. I already assign the service account and the scopes when creating it.

When I run a simple test for cloud storage it works like a charm.

```py
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()

print(storage_client._credentials.valid)
print(storage_client._credentials.service_account_email)
```

Gives me `True`, and the service account I am assigning to the Compute Engine instance.

But when I run

```py
import google.auth

credentials, project = google.auth.default()
print(credentials.valid)
print(credentials.service_account_email)
```

I get `False` and `default`

I haven't set a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable, and gcloud is not installed on the container.

As far as I know, Compute Engine passes down the metadata down to the container, so that it can access Google APIs using them (as it is the case of google storage).

I need to access some gRPC apis that are hosted in cloud run and need authentication. I am able to access them from my local dev environment using the service account, but I don't thing that passing explicitly the service account file to the container is the way to go. I'm trying to use the example [here](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#authenticate-with-google-using-an-oauth2-token) but I can't create the credentials.

Is there another method to create the credentials from the metadata? or am I missing something when I create/run the container?

Comment: Does [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da) article help? https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da

Comment: When you call `google.auth.default()`, the data structures are built, but API calls to create the credentials have not yet happened. You can force the generation of credentials with the method `refresh()`.

Comment: that's what was happening
thanks a lot